# Ionic to laravel post request

Tags: angularjs, laravel, http, ionic-framework, http-post

I have Laravel back-end API which can receive info from Ionic app. The problem I'm facing is sending an array of data through POST request...

This is my method:

```
Injection.ResourceFactory.postResource($http, SERVER, 'order/addToBasket', {
token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
quantity: $scope.quantity.value,
product_id: $scope.productId,
condiments: [$scope.condiments]
...
```

and `postResource` method is:

```
postResource: function ($http, SERVER, route, parameters, data) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: SERVER + route,
        data: data,
        params: parameters
    })
},
```

So everything is pretty straightforward, and works locally perfect. When I transfer everything online, suddenly the `condiments` aren't being sent. I have tried console logging it before and after the call, and as far as Ionic is concerned, an array is being sent...but for some reason not received?

When I make `Input::all()` call in Laravel i get only `token, quantity and product_id`. If I remove the brackets from `condiments: [$scope.condiments]` so that I send `condiments: $scope.condiments` I get only last item from the JSON being sent?

I can't seem to figure this one out...ideas?

Comment: Did you try manually encoding the condiments as `JSON.stringify([$scope.condiments])`

Comment: Exactly what I did...I have also forwarded everything as data, only token as parameter. It's working now, thanks

Comment: can u give me example code?

Comment: $http.post('http://localhost/abc/api/v1/categories/store', data, {
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
                       
                                            }
                    }
                ).success(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });

It shows problem like
Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
if i use 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;'
it works

Comment: i want to post as json